# Where does Delphi store property information set at design time?

Tags: delphi

Whenever you set a property in the Object Inspector, it must be writing some code or somehow saving the information somewhere, but where? I want to know so I can set properties and events from code but the question is the one above. Where's the code?

Comment: Where the Object Inspector saves property information has nothing to do with your ability to set properties from code. You probably learned how to set properties the very first day you started learning Delphi, and yet you didn't need to know anything about what happens at design time. What does your question's second sentence have to do with the first?

Comment: When you're using external packages, they have properties that take certain strings, for example. The easiest way to find out what they are (the specific property values) is to look at the code the object inspector writes, because the dropdown options are not always the same as the values the property takes. Thanks for the edit, it got me some rep.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's in the Delphi form file. This file has the same name as your unit `*.pas` source code file but has the `*.dfm` extension.

The current source code of your form you will get also if you're in form designer and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. There you can modify what you need and with the same keystroke go back to the designer.

You can check also what other files might be generated by Delphi for your project [`here`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/File_Extensions_of_Files_Generated_by_RAD_Studio).

Comment: Thanks. The same goes for event data then?

Comment: Yes, also events bindings are stored there. Just a sidenote, you can see the `*.dfm` code if you press `ALT + F12` if you are in the form designer. Forgot to mention, if you press it again, you will go back to the form designer.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The object inspector does not write the "code" so much as it just saves your selections in the form data.

If you want to modify any properties from the code, just write

```
SomeObject.property = "sdfsdfsdf";
```

Comment: Thanks; the guy above was a little quicker though :)

Comment: Sure, but note that you said that you want to know how to change properties from the code, and the first answer does not address that ;)

Comment: Cheers then. The alt-F12 shortcut was the thing I was really after though.

Answer (score 4):

Values of all the property stored into respective .dfm file.
Right click on the DFM design time form and select view as text or you can directly open dfm file in notepad